# Tab icon not showing

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to do a simple tab app in android with two tabs. My problem is that when I put this code, in the tab, only is shown the text, but no the icons. 
If I put the text to "" the icon is shown.

Could someone help me? My android version is 4.0.3.

Thanks a lot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/tabhost"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <TabWidget android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/tabs" />

     <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" >

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Contenido Tab 1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="Contenido Tab 2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

     </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and the activity code is

```
public class TabTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Resources res = getResources();

    TabHost tabs=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("mitab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("sss",
            res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now));
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec=tabs.newTabSpec("mitab2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("TAB2",
            res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map));
    tabs.addTab(spec);



    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

as you can see is very simple. But when I write `spec.setIndicator("",
                res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map));`
I can see the icon, bu when I write `spec.setIndicator("TAB2",
                res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map));`
I can only see TAB2, but no both of them.

It seems that there are no enougth space to show both. So I've tried to get increase the tab height with this

```
tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 150;
```

but not seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//your are over loading the 1st one so you can see only the last added one

```
 TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("mitab1");

        spec.setIndicator("sss",
                res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now));
 Intent sssIntent = new Intent(this, First.class);
 spec.setContent(sssIntent);
        tabs.addTab(spec);

TabHost.TabSpec spec2=tabs.newTabSpec("mitab2");
        spec2=tabs.newTabSpec("mitab2");
        spec2.setIndicator("TAB2",
                res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_map));
Intent sssIntent2 = new Intent(this, Second.class);
 spec2.setContent(sssIntent2 );
        tabs.addTab(spec2);
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more? I dont understand when You say overloading ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

I replaced the label name with null value.
Now I can see the icon alone..
Could not find out any other solution.

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabs.newTabSpec("mitab1");

spec.setIndicator("",
                  res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now));
Intent sssIntent = new Intent(this, First.class);
spec.setContent(sssIntent);
tabs.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: U r right.. we have to clear label of tab to see the icon..thats shit ... 
By the way Thanks for ur help buddy

Comment: if place null i'm able to see ..but not able to see the icon text below...can tell i want both icon and text to display...

Answer (score 2):

The visibility of the icon (together with the label) in the tab depend on the target device and the android platform version.

I had a deeper look into this issue and added more details and a solution at your other (quite similiar) question about this problem; It can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379708/414581

Answer (score 1):

Adding this in AndroidManifest.xml solved the issue.

```
<application 
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</application>
```