# How to add tab icons/text in Tabhost for ICS theme?

Tags: android

I am  getting back into android after taking a break from it for a while. However from reading it seems like if you use tabhost (or even actionbar) you cannot add tab icons on top of the tab text.

i.e you cant do this `tabspec.setIndicator("Tab1",drawableIcon)` It will just show the text with no icon.  Is there anyway you can add a tab with the icon on top of the text with the new ICS theme?

PS.  I am doing fragments with tabhost. In case you were wondering if i was using tabhost the old way (with activities)

Also, I know I can make my own theme to mimick ICS but I dont want to do that.

Comment: Looks like duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745092/icon-in-tab-is-not-showing-up

Answer (score 1):

To get the image to show

```
    int imageViewIndex = 1;
    if (ifICS) {
        imageViewIndex = 0;
    }

    ViewGroup idView = (ViewGroup) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(INDEX);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) idView.getChildAt(imageViewIndex);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable...);
```

then if you set the image View after the tabhost is made the image will be displayed