# TabHost on Android 4.2 - Icons and Colours Not Showing on Tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-4.2-jelly-bean

We're very new to Android development, so apologies if this is obvious.

We're implementing an activity using a tabbed view. The problem we are having is that the icons and proper colours on the tabs themselves do not show up properly on Jelly Bean (Android 4.2). They DO, however, display properly on earlier API levels, such as Gingerbread.

Please note: We did originally create the view using the deprecated TabActivity class. However, as far as I can tell, the "newer" way of doing this shouldn't be that different from the old? Please correct me if I am wrong.

This is the xml containing the tab host layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/Black">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <include layout="@layout/logo_bar"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Here is the relevant (I hope) activity code:

```
public class MainTabActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabHost.TabContentFactory
    private TabHost tabHost;
    // other instance variables ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec loginTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(GlobalConstants.LOGIN_ACTIVITY);
        loginTabSpec.setIndicator("Settings", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_settings_gear));
        loginTabSpec.setContent(this);

        TabSpec mainTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(GlobalConstants.MAIN_ACTIVITY);
        mainTabSpec.setIndicator("Lone Worker", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_settings_phone));
        mainTabSpec.setContent(this);

        tabHost.addTab(mainTabSpec);
        tabHost.addTab(loginTabSpec);
    }
```

This is what the tab itself looks like on Jelly Bean (bad version):[image]

And finally, this is what it should look like (on gingerbread... good version):[image]

So to re-iterate: The background colour of the tab is black (when it is normally that nice blue colour), and though it is difficult to tell from the bad screen shot, the icons for either tab are missing show up on jelly bean. I hope the problem is outlined enough here. Please let me know if I've left anything out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: can u plz tell me or guide me ... how to give margin between tabs in 4.2 .. in 4.1 margin on tabs is working fine and when i run same project in 4.2 , margin between tabs disappears and all the tabs occupy same space .... plz guide me if u have some solution for this ... thanks

Comment: @NipunGogia I have no idea, I've never tried to put margins between tabs. You might want to post your own question on this as my question has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Any reason for the random downvote?

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason in later versions of Android (>= ICS) tabs can only have a text label or an icon if you are using

```
setIndicator(CharSequence label, Drawable icon)
```

I suspect the reason you don't see any text is because the default text color for tabs in ICS is black, so its there just not visible on your black background.

A solution is to create your own view and use

```
setIndicator(View view)
```

More details here: [Icon in Tab is not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745092/icon-in-tab-is-not-showing-up/11379708#11379708)

and here http://ondrejcermak.info/en/programovani/custom-tabs-in-android-tutorial/