# FragmentTabHost with drawable icon

Tags: android, android-support-library, fragment-tab-host

I have implemented tabs using FragmentTabHost in support package, but the drawable icon is not shown?

How to show the drawable icon with FragmentTabHost?

```
mTabs = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
mTabs.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

mTabs.addTab(mTabs.newTabSpec("chapter").setIndicator("Chapter",getResources().
getDrawable(R.drawable.chapter1)), ContentFragment.class, null);

mTabs.addTab(mTabs.newTabSpec("section").setIndicator("section",getResources().
    getDrawable(R.drawable.favourite1)), SectionFragment.class, null);
mTabs.addTab(mTabs.newTabSpec("video").setIndicator("Video",getResources().
    getDrawable(R.drawable.video1)),VideoFragment.class, null);
mTabs.addTab(mTabs.newTabSpec("about").setIndicator("About",getResources().
    getDrawable(R.drawable.about1)),AboutFragment.class, null);
```

Comment: Do you use ICS for testing?

Comment: In ICS you should use `setIndicator(View view)` Please check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745092/icon-in-tab-is-not-showing-up/11379708#11379708) I had the same problem

Comment: it works but the selection of the menu disappears. How can i bring the selection back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. Apparently, `setIndicator(label, icon)` does not work correctly.
As a workaround, I used `setIndicator(view)` and created a simple custom view in `tab_indicator.xml`. For each tab, set the title and icon.

Comment: it works but the selection of the menu disappears. How can i bring the selection back?

Comment: @Lunatikul u were able to get that selection back?

Comment: I am following the same as you did, where am i wrong see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047245/add-selector-image-to-fragmenttabhost