# Icons are not displayed in Tabwidget

Tags: android, icons, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I'm trying to fill the `TabHost` with `TabSpec`'s, all is fine but the icons inserted with `setIndicator(text,drawable)` are not shown. I tried using my own pics, as well as the ones from android - none worked.

Here's my code:

```
tabs = (TabHost)findViewById( android.R.id.tabhost );
tabs.setup();

TabHost.TabSpec spec;
spec = tabs.newTabSpec( "destinationTab" )
           .setContent( R.id.destinationTab )
           .setIndicator( getString( R.string.enter_target ), getResources().getDrawable( android.R.drawable.ic_secure ) );
tabsDef.put( "destinationTab", R.id.destinationTab );
tabs.addTab( spec );

spec = tabs.newTabSpec( "freeHuntTab" )
           .setContent( R.id.freeHuntTab )
           .setIndicator( getString( R.string.free_hunting_button ), getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_my_own ) );
tabsDef.put( "freeHuntTab", R.id.freeHuntTab );
tabs.addTab( spec );
```

what am I missing?

TIA

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use my custom textView, but now I need to re-invent the whole tab's structure again, with all children, states etc. Heck, I only want to see my icons using the standard API!

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19541791/554281 , hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.photos_gray));
Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this,Photosactivity.class);
photospec.setContent(photosIntent);
```

This is working... But icons and texts are not parallely shown, any one will be viewable either Text or Icon