# How top set tab icon and label in FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, fragment-tab-host

I am using FragmentTabHost to implement bottom tabs with icon and label but following sentence shows only label

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),
            Fragment1.class, b);
```

I also see somewhere following works properly

```
setIndicator(View);
```

but I don't know syntax to set custom view in setIndicator

plz help
Thanks...

Comment: visit http://android.codeandmagic.org/android-tabs-with-fragments/

Comment: This also discusses this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745092/icon-in-tab-is-not-showing-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make custom view and set it as setIndicator(View v);

```
View chatView=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.chat_icon,null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator(chatView),
            Fragment1.class, b);
```