# icon in tabs not show !!! what should I do?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I'm trying to add icon in my tabspec in FragmentActivity . but when I add it . just text appear . but if I left the text blank . the icon will be appear . what should I do ?

```
public class FragmentTabs extends FragmentActivity {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    Resources r = getResources();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        TabSpec t = mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple " + i).setIndicator("a",
                r.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        mTabHost.addTab(t, SimpleFrag.class, null);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of the TabHost depends on the device and Android version, by default on some combinations of device/SDK version the TabHost will not display the tab icon if text is present.  See this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745092/icon-in-tab-is-not-showing-up) for more detail and a proposed solution.

Comment: now I'm trying on other devices . but nothing has been changed .